# istio is failing to install in a Kubernetes cluster built via Kops in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio

I can't get the demo profile to work with istioctl. It seems like istioctl is having trouble creating IngressGateway and the AddonComponents. I have tried doing the helm installation with similar issues. I did a fresh k8s cluster from kops and the same issue. Any help debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I am following these instructions. 
https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/#download

I am running

```
 istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --logtostderr
```

This is the output

```
2020-04-06T19:59:24.951136Z info    Detected that your cluster does not support third party JWT authentication. Falling back to less secure first party JWT. See https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens for details.
- Applying manifest for component Base...
✔ Finished applying manifest for component Base.
- Applying manifest for component Pilot...
✔ Finished applying manifest for component Pilot.
- Applying manifest for component IngressGateways...
- Applying manifest for component EgressGateways...
- Applying manifest for component AddonComponents...
✔ Finished applying manifest for component EgressGateways.
2020-04-06T20:00:11.501795Z error   installer   error running kubectl: exit status 1
✘ Finished applying manifest for component AddonComponents.
2020-04-06T20:00:40.418396Z error   installer   error running kubectl: exit status 1
✘ Finished applying manifest for component IngressGateways.
2020-04-06T20:00:40.421746Z info    
Component AddonComponents - manifest apply returned the following errors:
2020-04-06T20:00:40.421823Z info    Error: error running kubectl: exit status 1

2020-04-06T20:00:40.421884Z info    Error detail:


Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "STDIN": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s (repeated 1 times)


clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kiali unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kiali-viewer unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prometheus-istio-system unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kiali unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prometheus-istio-system unchanged

serviceaccount/kiali-service-account unchanged
serviceaccount/prometheus unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-citadel-dashboard unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-galley-dashboard unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-istio-mesh-dashboard unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-istio-performance-dashboard unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-istio-service-dashboard unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-istio-workload-dashboard unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-mixer-dashboard unchanged
configmap/istio-grafana-configuration-dashboards-pilot-dashboard unchanged
configmap/kiali configured
configmap/prometheus unchanged
secret/kiali unchanged
deployment.apps/grafana unchanged
deployment.apps/istio-tracing unchanged
deployment.apps/kiali unchanged
deployment.apps/prometheus unchanged
service/grafana unchanged
service/jaeger-agent unchanged
service/jaeger-collector unchanged
service/jaeger-collector-headless unchanged
service/jaeger-query unchanged
service/kiali unchanged
service/prometheus unchanged
service/tracing unchanged
service/zipkin unchanged


2020-04-06T20:00:40.421999Z info    
Component IngressGateways - manifest apply returned the following errors:
2020-04-06T20:00:40.422056Z info    Error: error running kubectl: exit status 1

2020-04-06T20:00:40.422096Z info    Error detail:

Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "STDIN": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s (repeated 2 times)


serviceaccount/istio-ingressgateway-service-account unchanged
deployment.apps/istio-ingressgateway configured
poddisruptionbudget.policy/ingressgateway unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/istio-ingressgateway-sds unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/istio-ingressgateway-sds unchanged
service/istio-ingressgateway unchanged


2020-04-06T20:00:40.422134Z info    

✘ Errors were logged during apply operation. Please check component installation logs above.

Error: failed to apply manifests: errors were logged during apply operation
```

I ran the below to verify install before running the above commands.

```
istioctl verify-install

Checking the cluster to make sure it is ready for Istio installation...

#1. Kubernetes-api
-----------------------
Can initialize the Kubernetes client.
Can query the Kubernetes API Server.

#2. Kubernetes-version
-----------------------
Istio is compatible with Kubernetes: v1.16.7.

#3. Istio-existence
-----------------------
Istio will be installed in the istio-system namespace.

#4. Kubernetes-setup
-----------------------
Can create necessary Kubernetes configurations: Namespace,ClusterRole,ClusterRoleBinding,CustomResourceDefinition,Role,ServiceAccount,Service,Deployments,ConfigMap. 

#5. SideCar-Injector
-----------------------
This Kubernetes cluster supports automatic sidecar injection. To enable automatic sidecar injection see https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#deploying-an-app
```

Comment: Have you tried to install other versions? I assume you tried to install 1.5.1? Could you try to use [istioctl upgrade](https://istio.io/docs/setup/upgrade/istioctl-upgrade/) after the installation with istioctl manifest apply fails?

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: Sure, let me know what are the results.

Comment: So the upgrade failed to complete. I am running 1.5.1 the most current version. Same issue. I think it has to do with not being able to configure the load balancer for some reason. I can create a AWS load balancer with kubectl and a bare-bones template without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your logs

> 2020-04-06T19:59:24.951136Z info    Detected that your cluster does not support third party JWT authentication. Falling back to less secure first party JWT.

---

As mentioned [here](https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens)

> To determine if your cluster supports third party tokens, look for the TokenRequest API:

```
$ kubectl get --raw /api/v1 | jq '.resources[] | select(.name | index("serviceaccounts/token"))'
{
    "name": "serviceaccounts/token",
    "singularName": "",
    "namespaced": true,
    "group": "authentication.k8s.io",
    "version": "v1",
    "kind": "TokenRequest",
    "verbs": [
        "create"
    ]
}
```

> While most cloud providers support this feature now, many local development tools and custom installations may not. To enable this feature, please refer to the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection).

---

> To authenticate with the Istio control plane, the Istio proxy will use a Service Account token. Kubernetes supports two forms of these tokens:
>
> Third party tokens, which have a scoped audience and expiration.
>   First party tokens, which have no expiration and are mounted into all pods.
>   Because the properties of the first party token are less secure, Istio will default to using third party tokens. However, this feature is not enabled on all Kubernetes platforms.
>
> If you are using istioctl to install, support will be automatically detected. This can be done **manually** as well, and configured by passing **--set values.global.jwtPolicy=third-party-jwt** or **--set values.global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt.**

---

If that won't work I would open a new github issue, or add a comment [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22319) as issue with installation is similar.